# Connecting the wallet of to your dApp and different Ethereum wallet types

Tags: web3js, metamask, wallets, walletconnect

How users can use connect their different wallets, like MetaMask, mobile wallets and hardware wallets with a dApp?

What wallets are supported?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are five categories of Ethereum wallets that can interact with dApps

- Browser built-in (Opera, Brave, ...)
- Browser extension (MetaMask, ...)
- Mobile wallets (Trust, Walleth, Pillar, ...)
- Account-based web wallets (Fortmatic, 3box, ...)
- Hardware wallets (Ledger, Trezor, ...)

Then there is a larger category of wallets that cannot integrate with dApps include generic wallet apps that lack the functionality to integrate with smart contracts.

- Many generic wallet apps that hold multiple coins (Xapo, ...)
- All cryptocurrecy exchanges (Binance, ...)
- Other "hot wallet" / "custodial" wallet services like BitGo

Different wallets have a different user experience to connect. For example, with MetaMask you get a Connect pop up. With mobile wallets, you scan a QR code.

[image]

[Web3modal](https://github.com/web3modal/web3modal) is a JavaScript library that allows you easily to pluck in any supported wallet to your dApp. It abstracts away different UX and protocols wallets provide.

Disclaimer: I am one of the contributors to Web3modal project

Comment: Any working example for Coinbase Wallet? I tried this example but didn't work https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal/blob/master/docs/providers/walletlink.md

Comment: Please ask Coinbase for Coinbase Wallet support. They are a multibillion publicly listed company. They should afford to offer their own developer support.

Comment: I will try. For me, their npm package doesn't work when not running on a Node server and their documentation is meager. Thank you, anyway.