# How do I develope a QR code for a 64 character hex string generated ethereum address?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereum-design, qrcode, creationcode

I am learning about how the 64 character hex string generated Eth Address is formed. 
Is there a program for this?

Comment: You can use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode to create QR code from ethereum address ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the

[QR Code Generator](https://www.qr-code-generator.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating direct addresses, there is now more modern approach for mobile wallets. It is called [WalletConnect](https://walletconnect.org/). It allows pass much more information to the wallet besides the payment address. Some wallets even allow sending push notifications to the payer.

Also check out the sister project [Web3Modal](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/82532/620) that works with different kind of wallets and not just mobile wallets.

Disclaimer: I am a contributor.