# walletlink and/or walletconnect on mobile browser

Tags: mobile-wallet, defi, walletconnect

I want to use DeFi apps over my mobile or mobile browser. Is there a way to connect to my wallet (Metmask, etc.) to the DeFi apps on my mobile or mobile browser?

I don't want to use the DeFi apps on my desktop only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here:

[Connecting the wallet of a user to your dApp / web3.js project and interacting with smart contracts using JavaScript](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82531/connecting-the-wallet-of-a-user-to-your-dapp-web3-js-project-and-interacting-w)

Any DeFi application must choose what wallets they support. Developers must add support for different wallet protocols. Besides mobile wallets, there are plenty of other wallet options. The most popular way to connect a mobile wallet is WalletConnect.

Comment: Hi Mikko. Thank you very much for your answer. I mean, I want to use the mobile browser, e.g. Android Chrome, to use the DeFi app and want to link it with a mobile wallet. No desktop is involved.

Comment: WalletConnect supports something called mobile linking https://twitter.com/WalletConnect/status/1314597510657302529