# Connecting to Coinbase wallet using Web3.js

Tags: web3js, coinbase

what is the way to connect coinbase wallet? like metamask?

I am building a website. I want to add coinbase payment gateway. How can I integrate this using web3?
If there is no way with web3 then what is the way?

Answer (score 2):

Coinbase Wallet does its own [WalletLink protocol](https://walletlink.org/) that is not supported by other wallets.

See also: [Connecting the wallet of to your dApp and different Ethereum wallet types](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82531/connecting-the-wallet-of-to-your-dapp-and-different-ethereum-wallet-types)

Comment: I am developing project using vanilla js. Where I will get cdn link of walletlink or walletconnect? do you have any Idea?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal-vanilla-js-example - I wrote it long time ago, so I am not sure if it is up to date or works anymore. But it should get you started.