# Cannot execute write transactions to dApp using coinbase wallet

Tags: wallets, dapps, web3-providers, coinbase

I'm trying to integrate the coinbase wallet into my dApp. I'm using the official [SDK](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/wallet-sdk/docs/welcome) to establish a connection with the injected provider. I'm able to send read requests to my smart contract, however I'm not able to send any writable ones. This only happens if I turn developer mode off. When using developer mode everything works as expected. The error I get is a general one and could not find anything on the web to justify this error.
Bellow is a screenshot with the error I'm getting:

https://prnt.sc/am1CaoJyJjwO

I inspected the the wallet's window for console errors and found the following:

https://prnt.sc/LRFuQ_f0oRNs

Is there any developer here that has experienced the same issue before? I tried to contacted the customer support of coinbase, but they did not provided any useful guidelines.

For account requests, I'm using the [EIP-1102](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1102) standard:

```
ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
```

I also tried to get the injected provider without the use of the SDK. This seems to work exactly the same way. From my undestanding, the coinbase wallet use an injected provider just like Metamask. I read at [this asnwer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/102819/9760) that it uses its own protocol. After running through the codebase at [GitHub](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-wallet-sdk) I couldn't find anything that might help.

Comment: Can you share how do you send requests (in JS) to the wallet? Which chain (eg. Ethereum, Polygon) are you using?

Comment: @KenzoAgada updated