# Is mandatory to use Metamask or other wallet for frontend interaction with dapp? (Is it possible to skip frontend web3.js part in dapp development))

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3.py, python

```
CONTRACT_SOURCE = """
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;


contract SimpleStorage{
    
    uint256 storeData;
    
    function setData(uint256 x) public{
        storeData = x;
    }
    
    function getData() public view returns(uint256){
        return storeData;
    }
}
"""
# compile solidity source code
compile_sol = compile_source(
    CONTRACT_SOURCE,
    output_values=["abi", "bin"],
    # solc_version="0.7.0"
)
# print(compile_sol)
# create an interface for compile contract
smartcontract_interface = compile_sol['<stdin>:SimpleStorage']
# print(smartcontract_interface)

simple_storage = WEB3.eth.contract(
    abi=smartcontract_interface["abi"],
    bytecode=smartcontract_interface["bin"]
)

# send ether from which accout ?
WEB3.eth.defaultAccount = WEB3.eth.accounts[0]

# Submit the transaction that deploys the contract
tx_hash = simple_storage.constructor().transact()

# Wait for the transaction to be mined, and get the transaction receipt
tx_receipt = WEB3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)

ASSETREGISTER = WEB3.eth.contract(
    # get the transaction from transaction address
    address=tx_receipt.contractAddress,
    abi=smartcontract_interface["abi"]
)
```

As a python developer I deployed my contract such way. If I will develop frontend, in that case do I need frontend interaction for wallet like metamask? I mean to say can I skip frontend web3.js part or not?

Comment: It's really not clear how posting your solidity code helps to answer the question. Also "developed that way" is not clear about what you did. I don't see the relationship between your contract and python. Globally your question seems hard to answer in the current state. Try to rewrite it and let me know.

Comment: Yes, you can skip the frontend entirely. The frontend is usually to make it easier to users interacting with the contract, if your users ara savvy enough it shouldn't be needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Web3 frontend is not needed, though it is the most popular way.

For example, native mobile apps sign the transactions differently. In theory, if a person is running the Python app locally on their computer, the signing can be can done using [WalletConnect](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82531/connecting-the-wallet-of-to-your-dapp-and-different-ethereum-wallet-types/82532#82532) protocol. This could be done from Python command line app also.